# Google analytics on react-admin

Tags: react-admin

What the best easiest way to use GA on react-admin app?

I known about npm module react-ga, but it tracks only homepage:

```js
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
ReactGA.initialize('UA-12345');
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

Is any universal way to see page view on each resource page and each actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using a custom history.

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

// create the history
const history = createBrowserHistory();

// listen for a route change and record page view
history.listen(location => {
  ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname);
});

// initialize GA
ReactGA.initialize('UA-000000000-1');

// record the first pageview because listen will not be called
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname);
```

Docs for `listen` with the history package: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md#listening

Do not forget to wire up your customer history in your `Admin` component:

```js
<Admin
  history={history}
>
  ...
</Admin>
```

See https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#history for more details